# Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH, where do I put it using the command line?

Tags: python, pip, selenium-chromedriver

I have downloaded `chromedriver`.

It lives in downloads. when I run `chromedriver` it starts up

I run my python command and get the error: `Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

How do I put it in path?

I just need to copy the exec file to the correct place but im not sure where to put it.

I dont want any of this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I just want to change the location

Im using a mac

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path to the exe file in the Chrome method.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
```

or place the exe in the scripts folder

**EX:**

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Comment: but where do I type this method in? I cant do it on the command line

Comment: @TheWalrus: I don't understand. All you need to do is mention the exe path inside  webdriver.Chrome("PATH") or Copy the chromedriver.exe to the Scripts folder in your python installation